# Parse Emmet string to AST in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, emmet

I want to use Emmet, or an equivalent, to expand a string abbreviation into a parsed tree that I can use in the rest of my JavaScript project.

It doesn't look like Emmet is designed to be consumed as an NPM module and I can't find any documentation in how to use it in a JavaScript project.

I'm looking for something equivalent to:

`emmet.parse('#main')` that outputs something equivalent to `{ type: 'div', attributes: { id: 'main' } }`.

I'm NOT interested in the HTML string output, I need the parse tree directly to use within my own project.

I'm really surprised that something like this doesn't exist.  Am I missing something?  How can I use just the parser portion of the Emmet as a library?

I tried `import` and `require` after `npm install emmet` but it seems it is not designed as a module and won't load.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to find it but eventually found `@emmetio/expand-abbreviation`.  Looks like it does what I need.

```
import { expand, parse } from '@emmetio/expand-abbreviation'
const ast = parse('#main>ul>li*3')
```